# Django Retrieve all Certifications based on names of the certificate

Tags: django, django-models

I want to retrieve all the `Prospects` that have all of the certifications
For example, if the certifications are A, B & C, only prospects that have exactly A, B & C should be returned. If they have more than ABC or less than ABC, they should be ignored.

In my model.py

```
class Certification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name


class Prospect(models.Model):
    certification = models.ManyToManyField(Certification, blank=True, related_name="certification_prospects")
```

How can I write a Django query to retrieve all the prospects that have strictly certification of A, B & C?

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.db.models import Count
certificates = Certification.objects.count()
prospect = Prospect.objects.annotate(total=Count('certification')).filter(total=certificates)
```

prospect var will return all object that have all certificates

Comment: This gives me this error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A' ` . It's caused by this line `prospect = Prospect.objects.filter(q)`. Any idea?

Comment: Can you explain your solution? To give a context, certifications are passed in as a list in the form of ['A', 'B', 'C']

Comment: It's not working. Your previous answer was more promising that ANDed the certificates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150120/discussion-between-neeraj-kumar-and-jasmine-rain).